# Boolean matrix form Python's dict of lists

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I have a dict of lists e.g.,

```
dictionary_test = {'A': ['hello', 'byebye', 'howdy'], 'B': ['bonjour', 'hello', 'ciao'], 'C': ['ciao', 'hello', 'byebye']}
```

I want to convert it into a boolean affiliation matrix for further analysis. Preferably, dict `keys` as column names, and list items as row names:

```
         A    B    C
  hello  1    1    1
 byebye  1    0    1
  howdy  1    0    0
bonjour  0    1    0
   ciao  0    1    1
```

Is it possible to do in Python (preferably so that I could write the matrix to a `.csv` file)?
I would image this is something I would have to do with `numpy`, correct?

An additional problem is that the size of the dictionary is unknown (both the number of keys and the number of elements in lists vary).

Comment: You want a `numpy` matrix? It looks like you might want a `pandas` DataFrame

Comment: Possibly, I have never worked with numpy before.

Comment: So you have a distinct list of the keywords used in the lists? hello, goodbye, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Here is an example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dictionary_test = {'A': ['hello', 'byebye', 'howdy'], 'B': ['bonjour', 'hello', 'ciao'], 'C': ['ciao', 'hello', 'byebye']}
>>> values = list(set([ x for y in dictionary_test.values() for x in y]))
>>> data = {}
>>> for key in dictionary_test.keys():
...  data[key] = [ True if value in dictionary_test[key] else False for value in values ]
... 
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, index=values)
             A      B      C
ciao     False   True   True
howdy     True  False  False
bonjour  False   True  False
hello     True   True   True
byebye    True  False   True
```

If you want the rows in certain order. Just manually set `values`.

Comment: Fails if a values is more than once in a list.

Comment: Sometimes I get empty lists as dict values? This code simply disregards the keys, whose values is an empty list. Is it possible to just append all zeroes?

Comment: Could you give an example @Zlo? Like 'D': []? The code should fill all false for 'D'.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Xin's answer, but instead iterates through each index (each word) and checks whether a given column in the original `dictionary_test` has that word in it.

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary_test = {'A': ['hello', 'byebye', 'howdy'], 'B': ['bonjour', 'hello', 'ciao'], 'C': ['ciao', 'hello', 'byebye']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary_test)

# all possible words (all possibles indices
words = {word for col in df.columns for word in df[col]}

# create a new DataFrame with the words as the index
d = pd.DataFrame(index = words)

# check whether a given column in your raw data contains a given index
# 1 if yes, 0 if no
for idx in d.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        d.loc[idx, col] = 1 if idx in set(df[col]) else 0
```

The result:

```
d
Out[6]: 
           A    B    C
hello    1.0  1.0  1.0
byebye   1.0  0.0  1.0
bonjour  0.0  1.0  0.0
howdy    1.0  0.0  0.0
ciao     0.0  1.0  1.0
```

Edit: In response to your getting `ValueError: arrays must all be same length` for keys whose values are empty lists, you could do this:

```
# find how long the longest list is
longest_list_len = max(map(len, dictionary_test.values()))
dictionary_test = {key: value + [None] * (longest_list_len - len(value)) for key, value in dictionary_test.items()}
```

You basically just fill in the difference in lengths between the arrays in `dictionary_test`. Then just change the `words` assignment line to this:

```
# Exclude the `None`s we added above to ensure equal length
words = {word for col in df.columns for word in df[col] if word != None}
```

And proceed with the remainder of the code from there!

Comment: Thanks! Although it sometimes happens that values are empty lists. If that's the case I get and error `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. Is it possible to have a full zero column, if the value is an empty list?

Comment: Check out the edit. You basically can fill in the blanks in the shorter lists with `None`s.